# LWC - uncheck checked boxes in lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, js

This successfully grabs all checked rows in my `lightning-datatable`:

```
this.template.querySelector("lightning-datatable").getSelectedRows();
```

But how do I select the associated checkboxes, so I can add `.checked = false`

Similar questions almost answer this question, but fall short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resets all selected checkboxes to deselected.

this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').selectedRows=[];